# добавить в избранное через javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax

Дано: н-количество карточек на странице о крипте. Задача состоит в том, чтобы пользователь мог нажать на звездочку (или ползунок) на этой карточке и таким образом добавить объекты на странницу избранного, где будет более другая информация с этих карточек. Как я понимаю, все нужно добавить в array и как-то это передать на страницу. Но не знаю с чего начать

```
function displayCoins(coins) {
    let html = "";
    
    for (const coin of coins) {
        html += `
            <div class="card">
                ${coin.symbol}
                <br>
                ${coin.name}
                <br>

                <button class="btn btn-primary" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#${coin.id}">
                    More Info
                </button>
                <div class="collapse" id="${coin.id}">
                    <div class="card-body">
                        <img src="${coin.image.small}">
                        ${coin.market_data.current_price.usd}$
                        <span> | </span>
                        ${coin.market_data.current_price.eur}€
                        <span> | </span>
                        ${coin.market_data.current_price.ils}₪
                    </div>
                </div>

            </div>
        `;
    }
    contentDiv.innerHTML = html; 
    
}

async function getJson(url) {
    const response = await fetch(url);
     json = await response.json();
    return json;
}
```

Comment: Начните с добавления идентификаторов карточек в массив-переменную.

Comment: @ЕгорБанин сделал и сохранил в localStorage

Comment: Теперь на странице избранного доставайте их и показывайте информацию с этих карточек.